# WP Twentyseventeen Menu Color Change Not Working

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, background-color

I've almost successfully changed the default white text and gray background menu color in the TwentySeventeen theme for WordPress by adding the lines below to a childtheme *style.css* stylesheet.

**Menu ScreenShot**

[image]

However, the menu still very briefly displays the default menu color as I mouse off any given selection in the sub-menus. I'm a hack when it comes to CSS and have spent hours trying to find a solution on line. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

```css
/*Change Drop Down Menu and Sub-Menu Hover and Text Color */

.menu a:hover,
.menu li:hover>a {
  background-color: rgb(220, 225, 200) !important;
  /* light green */
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to answer that without seeing in a live. Can you supply a link that reproduces the issue?

Comment: For a link to the site, please see the link above to organicentourage.com. Thanks.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with proper etiquette. I didn't realize I couldn't link to the site. I've removed the link. However, not knowing a lot about WP or CSS, I'm not  sure how I could have possibly known what code to include to reproduce the problem (minimal reproducible example). Is it OK to just say the name of the site without the link?

Comment: No. As shown in the link I gave you, you **MUST** reproduce the problem here **within your question**! Eventually this whole thing will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that because that there are 2 backgrounds, one on the `li`

[image]

and second on the `a`

[image]

The grey background is on the `li` so you just need to "reset" it

```css
.main-navigation li li:hover,
.main-navigation li li.focus {
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I wanted to show a screen shot of the OP site, including the reference to the style.css file etc. I think that in this case, the images is required.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Mosh Feu. I looked at that CSS for hours and tried every combination I could think of. I don't really know much about CSS so I just kept going around and around. The images help me understand how to better read the CSS so I can learn. I definitely need to use a better code inspector because I was not seeing the background properties under the .menu and .main-navigation classes you showed. This was super helpful!

Comment: With pleasure :) If you need more help in the future, you can find my details in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu?tab=profile). Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to "reset" the background with `background: none` (but not `background: #767676`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Using "none" makes the menu snappier. For others that are like me and need all the help they can get, here's the CSS that worked. 
    /* Change Drop Down Menu and Sub-Menu Hover and Text Color */
    /* There are two classes with the menu background property */
    .main-navigation li li:hover,
    .main-navigation li li.focus {
      background: none; /* blank out upper level background */
      color: none;
    }

    .menu a:hover,
    .menu li:hover > a {
      background-color: rgb(220,225,200); /* set background to light green */
      color: #000000 !important;
    }

Comment: Great. You're welcome to reach me whenever you need.